# VBA Excel - List of Prime Numbers less than User Input

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a macro in VBA Excel, that will generate list of all prime number equal or less than user input...Please give me the Idea, Thanks RS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim ss As Single, i As Single
    ss = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter and integer", Type:=1)
    k = 1
    For i = ss To 1 Step -1
        If IsPrime(i) Then
            Cells(k, 1) = i
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function IsPrime(Num As Single) As Boolean
     Dim i As Long
     If Num < 2 Or (Num <> 2 And Num Mod 2 = 0) _
      Or Num <> Int(Num) Then Exit Function
     For i = 3 To Sqr(Num) Step 2
         If Num Mod i = 0 Then Exit Function
     Next
     IsPrime = True
End Function
```

From:

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/06/30/is-this-number-prime/

**EDIT#1**:

To use a MsgBox to output the results, use this for MAIN:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim ss As Single, i As Single
    Dim s As String
    ss = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter and integer", Type:=1)
    k = 1
    For i = ss To 1 Step -1
        If IsPrime(i) Then
            s = s & "," & i
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

But a MsgBox is limited in how much material they can display.

Comment: You got my question correctly, but what if I have to print all these numbers on same line on message box??